# Change default font in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, fonts

The default font in Visual Studio 2010 is `Microsoft Sans Serif`. 
 Is there a way I can change the default font for the current project so that I don't have to change it for every forms and controls I add ?

Comment: I have a similar problem. My Windows fonts were deleted, and VS studio crashed. I've restored the windows fonts and I've reseted the VS visual settings to default. But VS keeps tryng to set any control text Font to Arial, at old and new projects. I was not able to make VS go back to the default font M. Sans Serif.

Comment: Be careful with this if you are using form auto scaling. In my experience, overriding the base form's font and allowing it to be inherited by child controls can mess us your form scaling. I think there are other SO posts to this effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do what you require is to create a custom template.

- Create a new WinForm project
- Customize the default form with your preferred font
- Save the project
- On the file menu select Export Template
- Follow the wizard

Now when you add a new form you should find the new template in the list of the available items

Comment: In later VS versions (eg 2019), Export Template... is under the Project menu item.

Answer (score -1):

Here's a better solution: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165337%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

:-)

Comment: This is to change the fonts of the Windows used by Visual Studio (e.g.: the window where you write code). The question is about the forms you create for your project!